When is $x \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ a square?
Theorem:
Let $p$ be odd prime. The map $\Phi_p{:\mathbb{Q}}_p^{\times}/\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times^{}2} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $up^n \mapsto (\mu((\frac{u}{p})),n \mod 2)$ is a isomorphism.
Where $\mu (-1)=\overline{1}$, $\mu(1)=\overline{0}$.
If $a \in \mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}/\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times^{}2}$, then $a$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.
Consider the following:
Let $x \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ and I want to know if $x$ is a square or not (in $\mathbb{Q}_p$).
Then I need to write $x$ as $p^nu$ with $u \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$. After that it is easy to calculate $\Phi_p(x)$.
There are $4$ possible outcomes $(1,1),(0,1),(1,0),(0,0)$.
Now I am stuck on the meaning of those outcomes.
(i.e. for what outcome is x a square/not a square and why?).


If $a \in \mathbb{Q}_p^\times/\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times 2}$, then $a$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

I'm not sure if there is a typo in the above sentence of yours, since it is not only not true, but if it were true, it would be a (wrong) answer to your question.
The real answer is quite simple: $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times2}$ is the set of squares in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (except $0$), by definition. Now, for a non-zero $x \in \mathbb{Q}_p^\times$, the following are equivalent:

$x$ is a square;
$x \in \mathbb{Q}_p^{\times2}$;
$x$ is sent to the identity $1 \mathbb{Q}_p^{\times 2} \in \mathbb{Q}_p^\times/\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times 2}$ by the quotient map;
$\Phi_p\left(x \mathbb{Q}_p^{\times 2}\right) = (0, 0)$, the identity of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. (Or say $\Phi_p(x) = (0,0)$, depending on whether the actual domain of $\Phi_p$ is $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times / \mathbb{Q}_p^{\times 2}$ or $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times$.)


Not a typo, just a thinking error. Thank you very much!
